# C: exec to my own exe file

Tags: c, exec, fork, exe

I am using linux to try and exec to run a different child process to parent process.

I can exec a child process to run the ps command fine.

```
int x = fork();

if (x == 0)
{
    execl("/bin/ps","ps", NULL);   
}
```

However as soon as I try to exec to a .exe file that I have created from my own c file like this `gcc -v test.c -o test.exe`. by running this code:

```
int x = fork();

if (x == 0)
{
    execl("/Desktop/test","test.exe", NULL);    
}
```

Then nothing happens. If I printf the above `execl` statement then it returns -1.

Can anyone let me know whats going on?

A few notes:

1. the test.exe file (created from my c source code) icon shows up a windows icon (why, and is this the problem?)
2. When running test from terminal it executes fine

Comment: Can you verify that you can run the .exe manually?

Comment: You probably have Wine installed (hence the icon). In Unices you don't put .exe extension on executables, it has no meaning.

Comment: when i run test.exe from terminal it executes as it should yes

Comment: and yes I do have wine installed,so thats prbably it, thanks

Comment: Put a `perror("execl() failed");`  right after the call to `execl()` to receive more detailed information on the error.

Comment: @meskobalazs: It's not necessary as under windows, but under IXish systems you are free to name your files as you like, even suffing then `.exe`.

Comment: Did you try calling the executable by its full name `execl(".../test.exe", ... `?

Comment: However, please tell us on/in which platform/enviroment you observe this.

Comment: Also it shall be `execl(..., (char*) NULL);`.

Comment: @alk of course, you are free to do as you please, but most people would assume that an exe file is a windows binary (or a Mono executable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that your desktop folder is at `~/Desktop/`. The tilde means your `home` folder.

Comment: yes, that's it, thanks! also, for some reason it also prints '-1' along with the tests output, any idea why?

Comment: That must be the return value of the child process, but I don't know why it prints it to *stderr*